# Applying a .patch file? (patch for a jquery-ui file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, diff, patch

I found a .patch file that would fix an issue I have with jQuery-ui.
However, after googling for a long, long time, I can't find any good answer to this.
(I haven't dealt with .patch files before).

You can get the patch file [here](https://forum.jquery.com/viewFile.do?fileId=14737000002031675&forumGroupId=14737000000003003) to check it out, if that helps.

I know I might have to downgrade my jQuery-ui for it to work, as the patch is from 2011.

Thanks in advance.

- Ken B.

**EDIT** I found another way around my problem. **SOLVED**

Comment: What's the issue you are trying to fix?

Comment: It is a git patch file. The proper way to apply it would be to clone the jQuery UI repo then apply it. See: https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git Though, as these are merely a couple instructions, you can open the uncompressed source, find those lines and follow the delete and insert line instructions manually. But you shouldn't really be editing the jQuery UI file itself as you lose CDN hosting ability and you'd have to patch it every time you upgrade. Better make it a separate plugin.

Comment: If only I had the skills to make my separate plugin. Hehe..
But good tip about CDN hosting, didn't really think about that.

I'm adding a already made javascript..addon if you will, for the snap function in jQuery-ui. As of now, the snapMode only works with :'outer', 'inner' and 'both'. This patch will add so you can use :'corner'. Which makes your object snap to all 4 corners, making it much more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `patch` executable. Normally you will have this if you are working on Linux or Mac OS I guess. (The [Wikipedia article on patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29), which actually contains some nice usage examples).

From the command line, while located in the same folder as the files you want to patch, you type:

```
patch < path/to/your/file.patch
```

where `path/to/your/file.patch` of cause is the path to the file you want to patch the jQuery-UI source with.

Comment: As far as I know the patches that git creates are just normal patches and can be applied normally, you might have to provide a `-p1` param to `patch` thought. But you are right in your comment, it would be better to use git to apply it to a clone of the jQuery-UI git.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've stated that I'm on a Win OS. I tried messing with TortoiseMerge etc. But no luck there. Easiest way might be to just copy/paste the data manually. Although it's quite hard to find out where to actually put it, as he's probably changed it quite a bit.